# Clojure OAuth Libraries

Tags: oauth, clojure, oauth-2.0

There are a number of Clojure libraries available for OAuth, but not all providers and protocols are supported. What are the Clojure library options for OAuth and which providers do they support, especially OAuth 2?

Comment: Of course, you can call Java libraries from Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. The standard recommendation would likely be Chas Emerick's `friend` (https://github.com/cemerick/friend) which packs most of the options you're likely to be interested in, and which a number of other libraries build upon.

There are also somewhat more contained libraries like `clauth` (https://github.com/pelle/clauth) which specifically target OAuth 2 but don't aim to solve your security needs in a comprehensive fashion.